# virtual machine and mint linux installation of apache

Tags: linux, apache

I install mint on a virtual machine workstation
What command is used to install Apache web server ?

I have tried

admin> apt-get install Apache
but no such files are found on any server. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
   sudo apt-get install apache2

Answer (score 0):

Try `apt-cache search apache` to find out the name of the relevant packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First you have to open up Terminal

```
Applications > Accessories > Terminal
```

Copy paste the following command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```